# Lambda to select items from a list based on another list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a scenario where I need to select certain objects out of a list of objects

e.g

`List<MyObjects> selectedObject = myObjectList.Where(o => o.LastName in (checkedObj.LastName where checkedObj.IsSelected == true )`

How can I accomplish this using lambda expressions?

Comment: Why is this being  negged? The bad grammar?

Comment: sorry people for the bad grammer. something went wrong during typing. i only checked the Code before Posting. Thanks to Steve for editing. :)

Answer (score 5):

Using `Any` would be one solution:

```
List<MyObjects> selectedObject = myObjectList.Where(o =>
    checkedObjList.Any(c => c.LastName == o.LastName && c.IsSelected))
```

(Assuming you have a `checkedObjList` from which your above `checkedObj` was taken.)

Comment: `and` should be `&&`, right? ;) I also changed the assignment `=` to comparison `==`.